# Can't access json data from API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, axios

#### Assigning new value in profile ( initially 'c' )

```
componentWillMount() {
//state declaration
    this.state = {
      profile: 'c'
   }
    //changing state
    axios.get('http://15.166.45.231:8080/notifications?
         user_email=anurag@anurag.com')
          .then(response => this.setState({
              profile: 'Changed' , function () {
                console.warn(this.state.weather);
            }
            }))
          .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
          });
```

#### Data remains unchanged

Output

`c`

Instead I even tried explicitly trying to assign data as **Changed** but in vain.

#### The original API fetching code :

```
componentWillMount() {
//state declaration
    this.state = {
      profile: {}
   }
    //changing state
    axios.get('http://15.166.45.231:8080/notifications?
         user_email=anurag@anurag.com')
          .then(response => this.setState({
              profile: response.data , function () {
                console.warn(this.state.weather);
            }
            }))
          .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
          });
```

**data** is the attribute of the returning *response*.( One of the things which get returned like headers etc ).

**Sample json data :**

```
[{"date": "2017-03-25 05:43:01.362975+00:00", "from": "anurag", "status": "Pending", "type": "1", "to": null}, {"date": "2017-03-25 06:00:46.736505+00:00", "from": "anurag", "status": "Pending", "type": "2", "to": null}]
```

Comment: do you understand what the object you are passing to setState, ie `{ profile: 'Changed' , function ()  { console.warn(this.state.weather); } }` actually looks like? It's an object with two properties named `profile` and `function` - is that what you intended? in the first example you totally ignore `response` anyway

Comment: I think you have misplaced a `}` ... setState is called like `setState(nextState, callback)` ...

Answer (score 0):

Your callback method in setState is not correct. It should be:

```
axios.get('http://15.166.45.231:8080/notifications?
         user_email=anurag@anurag.com')
          .then(response => 
                 this.setState({ profile: response.data},()=> {
                console.warn(this.state.weather);

            }))
          .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//changing state
axios.get('http://15.166.45.231:8080/notifications?
     user_email=anurag@anurag.com')
      .then(response => this.setState({
          profile: response.data , function () {
            console.warn(this.state.weather);
        }
        }))
      .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
      });
```

This is your code. It has a really simple problem.

```
There are 2 forms of setState - 
1. setState(obj, function callBackAfterStateUpdation)
2. setState(function(previousState, propsWhenStateIsUpdated), function callBackAfterStateUpdation)
```

where the second argument is optional in both forms.

You are using the first form which accepts an object that represents your current state and a callback to be executed after setting the state.

```
response => this.setState({
          profile: response.data , function () {
            console.warn(this.state.weather);
        }
        })
```

This is what is wrong with your code. It should be

```
response => this.setState({ profile: response.data }, function () {
            console.warn(this.state.weather);
        })
```

Also, it is a good practice to keep consistency in your code. You are using - function(){} - at some places, while fat arrow functions - () => {} - at others. Choose either one, but stick to it.